# A strange behavior after replacing `mvn clean install` with `mvn clean package`

Tags: java, maven

My project gets two dependencies, and each has `com.Foo` class. Difference is the second one has method `setVersion`.

```
dependency_1  com.Foo does not have method setVersion

dependency_2  com.Foo.serVersion
```

- It's ok when I use `mvn clean install` to build the `.war` file.
- When I change it to `mvn clean package`, it can compile success. But at runtime, `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown.

I know it's not good idea to import class with same name. And I solve this problem by removing `dependency_1`.

But I want to know why it make a difference after using `mvn clean package`? Or there might be other problem which I did not notice causing this behavior?

Comment: This should not be normal behavior (e.g. difference between install and pacakge) and is not related to maven. You have 2 classes with the same name on the classpath - depending on the Classloader it will load one of those.

Comment: @hovanessyan Let's assume `dependency_1 ` is totally redundant, I did not refer any class(except Foo) from it. Does it will also be put into the `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: What you put in WEB-INF/lib depends entirely on your building process, right? I mean you can have maven dependency plugin copying jars there, you might have a custom script copying more stuff. When this folder is on the classpath the classloader loads the classes from the jars and there's no predictable behavior. Java has pluggable classloader system - I can write a custom classloader so that when it finds two classes with the same name to load the one which is declared first on the classpath. That will be different from when running the app on another JRE.

Comment: @hovanessyan Yeah, thanks. I will check whether if the two jar was put into the classpath. If they does, then I believe this problem is not related to maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maven the install is just another phase that takes the artifact produced during the `package` phase and puts it into the local .m2 repository.

**Blaming Maven**

So, first of all, I would have verified that `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package` produce the same artifact in your target directory.

For 99 % of projects, they should be the same, although technically it's possible to write a Maven plugin that will be applied to install phase or any phase between package and install. In default Maven lifecycle there are [some phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in-between:

You can add plugins that will be applied during any phase, so first of all check that you don't have

- pre-integration-test
- integration-test
- post-integration-test
- verify

So again, if you suspect Maven, just run `mvn clean package`, go to 'target' dir, copy the artifact aside, then run `mvn clean install`, and compare the target.

If in your organization there is a policy that prohibits running `mvn install` (although its a fairly weird decision, because install doesn't touch any remote stuff and works locally on your computer), then you can always override a default Maven repository location like this:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=/alternate/repo/location
```

Now, that the Maven part, if you see that the artifacts are the same, then the is no reason to blame Maven :) Check your container then

**Blaming the container**

This is where the things become really complicated because usually containers (and I assume here you have a container like tomcat or wildfly, for example),  have a hierarchy of classloaders. Needless to say classes that have the name FQDN but loaded by different classloaders are totally different classes.

So, if there are 2 classes with the same FQDN in different jars, and both jars are in the WAR (in the classpath), the classloader will choose the first that appears in the classpath and will load it.

In Java (unlike C++ for example), the classes are a loaded dynamically (on-demand) upon the first attempt to load the class and not necessary right during the program startup.

Add to this a class loader hierarchy (parent classloader for all "common" classes, and classloader per artifact), a policy to change the order of searching (parent-first loading vs. child-first loading) configurable at the level of a container, and you'll get a fairly complicated policy which can't be really resolved here in the answer, if you'll want to understand what happens there you'll have to debug a container.

Of course, my advice is obvious - just don't maintain these two classes in the same package - opt of different classes (different packages, different class names), maybe interface with different implementations, there are many options.

But my gut feeling tells that you already know this, so it can barely be countered as an answer. :)

Comment: Thank you sir, this helps a lot and shows me the way. I will check the target folder.

Comment: I compared the target folders, this `dependency_1.jar` is always in. But one have `Foo.class`, the other does not. Finally, I found out that the publisher of `dependency_1.jar` added `Foo.class` recently.  That's the problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: Very insightful answer!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a classloader issue,  are you sure the results are repeatable over a number of tests?

If you have 2 classes with the same identifier on the classpath, the order in which the dependencies are loaded becomes significant, with subsequent classes overwriting earlier ones.  Most often this issue manifests itself as "inconsistent behaviour", especially where you don't define the order yourself (via `-classpath`) and the dependencies are loaded from a directory (`WEB-INF/lib` for example), your destiny is then in the hands of whatever IO library reads the files.

You're right to remove the duplicate dependency though, it's a recipe for disaster!

Comment: I have been deploying this application many times by `mvn clean install`. It never throws this exception. Even I have two classes have same identifier in my classpath. But after I switch it to `package`(`install` is not allowed in my company any more), the problem happens.

Comment: That makes the problem a lot more interesting :)